# Distribution provisioning profile will not be set to "Active"

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

The distribution provisioning profile that I use for my iOS app "BodBot Personal Trainer" has been working without issue for the past several months. Without any change from my part, it became invalid. It appears that the accompanying Certificate had expired a few days before I found that the profile became invalid, so I assumed I just needed to "Generate" the profile again. This did not work. I then verified that the related App ID was fully functionality, which it was. I then created a new Certificate as well as a new Provisioning Profile associated with that Certificate. None of these actions seem to successfully result in a working Distribution Provisioning Profile associated with my App ID.

Odd note: Each time I Generate the Provisioning Profile, it shows up as "Active" for around 10 minutes, at which point it shows up as "Invalid"

Question: There's little/no detail as to what is going on here. Any help, even if it's just a place to look for additional data for a diagnosis, would be very much appreciated. When it comes to provisioning profiles, I'm pretty lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like symptoms of automatic provisioning resolving done via XCode. Even though it works sometimes, it's good practice to avoid using this feature, as usually it is invalidating current profiles for some reason.

Consider trying out brand new [tool](https://codesigning.guide) by F.Krause, which will allow to centralise provisioning profiles and avoid their constant invalidation/re-generation.

Comment: Awesome. That fixed things. Thanks for your help! You rule.